# Is it possible to have more than one stream in single microservice?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

It's possible to have more than one stream in single microservice?

This is my yaml.

```
 bindings:
    input:
       destination: topic1
       content-type: application/*+avro
    output:
       destination: topic2
       content-type: application/*+avro
```

Can I have more input and output?

Can I have different serialize class for each stream?

```
producer-properties:
  key.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
  value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just add new bindings:

```
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: topic1
          content-type: application/*+avro
        inputStream1:
          destination: topic_input_1
        inputStream2:
          destination: topic_input_2

        output:
          destination: topic2
          content-type: application/*+avro

        output2:
          destination: output_topic_2
```

And provide EnableBinding and the other extra annotations like StreamListener:

```
    @EnableBinding(MultipleDesBinding.class)
    public class YourApplication {


        @StreamListener
        @SendTo("output")
        public KStream<String, String> topology1(@Input("inputStream") KStream<String, String> inputKStream,
                                                 @Input("inputStream1") KStream<String, String> inputStream1KStream) {

        }

        @StreamListener
        @SendTo("output2")
        public KStream<String, Long> topology2(@Input("inputStream2") KStream<String, String> inputStream2KStream) {

        }
    }


    interface MultipleDesBinding {

        @Input("input")
        KStream<?, ?> input();

        @Input("inputStream1")
        KStream<?, ?> inputStream1();

        @Input("inputStream2")
        KStream<?, ?> inputStream2();

        @Output("output")
        KStream<?, ?> output();

        @Output("output2")
        KStream<?, ?> output2();

    }
```

You can take a detail look in the document: [Imperative programming model](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_imperative_programming_model).

Comment: Thanks. But how I can differentiate producer and consumer properties for each stream in yaml? I have added config in question.

Comment: Please can You edit your answer? Output method needs Output annotations?

Comment: There seem to be a multiple binder config, each binder for each broker, but I can not get to to work https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#multiple-binders

Comment: oh, it does work, I just had the wrong config, please try it out